# Itunes blocked app publish because of Stripe payments. In-App Purchase was requested

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, stripe-payments, itunes

We have a WebView based iOS app.

Before we used micro transactions to buy digital content inside the app using Stripe (payment platform)

Last app update was blocked by Itunes:

> Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase
>
> Your app unlocks or enables additional functionality with mechanisms
>   other than the App Store, which is not appropriate for the App Store.
>
> Specifically, the app allows parents to purchase internal currency to be used in app via STRIPE.

We had to disable Stripe for now in IOS to deploy the app.

At this moment we need to do transactions in app but to buy Crypto currency, not to buy internal currency.

The question here is:

Can I use Stripe platform for this or do I need to use itunes payment platform?

This will be a new application, not an update of the old one.

Comment: You can only use Stripe to purchase physical goods and explicitly *not* digital goods (including digital currency), I believe.  You will likely need to reach out to them about this.